# how can i check if key exists with certain value inside a foreach php array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

hi i have php array that will always look like the below. i am using a foreach. so i want to check if key  `$value['month']` with value 01exists. i mean `$value['month']` will always exist but what i want to check is . does it exist with a certain value.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => 03
        [value] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => 05
        [value] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => 06
        [value] => 12
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => 07
        [value] => 12
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => 08
        [value] => 1
    )

)
```

Comment: So iterate with `foreach` and check. What is the problem?

Comment: Btw there's no key `month` in your array.

Comment: in other words this is what i want `foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
 //if $value['label'] exists with value 01 then do something
 //in other words if this exists
 //Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => 01 [value] => 2 ))
}`

Comment: And what? What is your problem?

Comment: @u_mulder i meant label not month. i just did my foreach above but i dont know how to check ..please look above cooment

Comment: First show what you had been tried and where show proper array

Comment: `if ($variable == 'value')` this is what you're looking for?

Comment: okay from my above multidimensional array how can i check if this array exists in it `Array ( [label] => 01 [value] => 0 )`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate using `foreach()` and compare:

```
// whatever the corresponding label should be
$label = '01';

foreach ($data as $key => element) {
    if (is_array($element) 
        && array_key_exists('label', $element)
        && '01' === $element['label']
    ) {
        // found matching element with $key
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use `array_walk()` to iterate:

```
// whatever the corresponding label should be
$label = '01';

array_walk($data, function (array $element) use ($label) {
    if (array_key_exists('label', $element) && $label === $element['label']) {
        // found matching element
    }
});
```

Alternatively, use `array_filter()` if you want to filter and find an array of matching elements:

```
// whatever the corresponding label should be
$label = '01';

$matching = array_filter($data, function (array element) use ($label) {
    return array_key_exists('label', $element) && $label === $element['label']
}); 

if (0 !== count($matching)) {
    // found at least once in $data
}
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: this work perfect..but what if i only wanted to know about label and do not worry what value is "value" all i am interested in was if label with certain value exists? how woud you go about?

Comment: Let me adjust that for you.

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look again?